# Using SUM with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, union

I've been looking into this all day, trying all kinds of solutions, but just can't get anything to work.  I don't think it's all that complicated.  I have two tables that have common fields, one of which is 'jobamount'.  The two tables are 'LiveMusic' and 'VO'.  I'm just trying to get the total of all the values of each table using UNION.  So, my basic statement right now is:

```
SELECT SUM(jobamount) FROM LiveMusic WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(jobamount) FROM VO WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%'
```

This works fine as far as, I'm getting two results, the sum of all the values from each table.  How do I `SUM` these, `GROUP` them, whatever?  I just need to combine these into one.  Thanks much!

Comment: well it's simple. just `SELECT (SELECT SUM(jobamount) FROM LiveMusic WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%') + (SELECT SUM(jobamount) FROM VO
WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%')  AS amount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sum the sums:

```
SELECT SUM(jobsum) AS totalsum FROM (
SELECT SUM(jobamount) AS jobsum FROM LiveMusic WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%' UNION ALL SELECT SUM(jobamount) AS jobsum FROM VO WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%'
) sums;
```

Or sum the values after union all:

```
SELECT SUM(jobamount) AS totalsum FROM (
SELECT jobamount FROM LiveMusic WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%' UNION ALL SELECT jobamount AS jobsum FROM VO WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%'
) jobamounts;
```

You can run an [EXPLAIN](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/) on both queries to see which one runs faster for you.

Comment: Ladi, thank you!  You and Spyker had perfect solutions, both worked very well.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

you can use [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT SUM(X.jobamount) 
  FROM (
        SELECT jobamount FROM LiveMusic WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT jobamount FROM VO        WHERE jobdate LIKE '2019%'
       ) X
```

Comment: Spyker, thank you!!!  That worked perfectly.  That was something I hadn't tried (obviously).  I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

like this..

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount_sum)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(jobamount) AS amount_sum
        FROM
            LiveMusic
        WHERE
            jobdate LIKE '2019%'
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                SUM(jobamount) AS amount_sum
            FROM
                VO
            WHERE
                jobdate LIKE '2019%'
    ) t
```